# What do you find unclear?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am confused by why people are finding my questions unclear. In my last question, I asked whether A believes B is the case, and I gave reasons I believe B. I also quoted instances of A discussing B, which were not conclusive either way but clearly show that A definitely states that B occurs at some time.

It was convoluted, but that is not sufficient for a lack of clarity, *definitely* not if it cannot be asked in a less convoluted way.

And I understand that, in your non-expert opinion, it is unlikely that A believes B. But again, how does that make it unclear? A question is exactly that, and it is just mistaken to close a question because it contains something you disagree with (B).

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/99207/hobbes-and-nietzsche

Can you imagine if atheist philosophers refused to answer questions from people that believe in God, so that some questions, e.g. given I believe in God I wondered if Aquinas thinks Jesus has a substance, are just unsuitable?

I do not know if you will have access to the question, but anyway it is an ongoing problem I am having with this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentatively, this is my answer: stackexchange has and presumably always will be a place for users to conform to the most popular opinion on the site. You can see this in e.g. the way that you are encouraged to downvote questions you disagree with on meta, the way that unreferenced answers are upvoted as "good" answers because you agree with them, etc..

It's probably a hang over from its coding days, when you could only answer questions if you could code, etc..